# Debugging Python C++ extension from Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have written some python C++ extension that I want to debug while running it from python (interactively) using Visual Studio Code on Linux.

I have set-up my launch.json as follows for attach. Basically it is using my python interpreter as the program

```
    { 
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "/home/mike/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3/bin/python",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. I am pretty new to Visual Studio Code for debugging, so I might be missing something trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed trivial. Just attach the correct process. Keeping the answer here as it is not trivial to find on the web.

Comment: Good hint. You can consider marking it as answer after 48 hours and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the VScode extension "Python C++ Debug". It automatically attaches the C++ debugger to the python debugger for you. Also if you don't have a launch.json file ready, it sets up all configurations you need when clicking on 'create a launch.json file'.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough! I struggled with getting a launch configuration that works. The "Python C++ Debug" extension was super easy to use.